# Anyone seen this integer topology in use? "$k$th-power-spaced integer topology".

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, integers

Fix an offset $b \in \Bbb{Z}$ and define $U_c = \{cX^k + b : X \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.  Let $B = \{U_c: c \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ form a basis for a topology on the set $\Bbb{Z}$.  I have proved that it is indeed a basis for a topology.  Was wondering if anyone has used it in a paper, and if so where?

- The space is $T_0$ but not $T_1$.
- $\{\varnothing\} \cup \{U_c\}_{c \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is a $\pi$-system.

A similar thing can be done with $U_c = \{k X^c + b : X \in \Bbb{Z}\}, \ c \geq 1$.

Comment: Is $k$ also fixed ahead of time? As to its properties, clearly it's not $T_1$, since $b$ is in every nonempty open set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes $k$ is fixed.

Comment: Some similar topologies were considered below:

Comment: Solomon W. Golomb *[Arithmetica topologica](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/700933/Toposym_01-1961-1_41.pdf)* In: (ed.): General Topology and its Relations to Modern Analysis and Algebra, Proceedings of the symposium held in Prague in September 1961. Academia Publishing House of the Czechoslovak Academy of Sciences, Prague, 1962. pp. 179--186.

Comment: Solomon W. Golomb *A Connected Topology for the Integers*, The American Mathematical Monthly 10 (1959), **66**:8. [references](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/248858352_A_Connected_Topology_for_the_Integers)

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks!